Cannot mix gestures with react-native-reanimated-carousel and react-native-gesture-handler
When migrating from a custom carousel to react-native-reanimated-carousel, I aimed to integrate additional gestures with the new <Carousel /> component provided by the library, but encountered difficulties.
To incorporate additional gestures, I understand that I need to wrap my carousel with a <GestureDetector/> from react-native-gesture-handler. Moreover, I know that combining gestures can be achieved with Gesture.Simultaneous, as react-native-reanimated-carousel utilizes react-native-gesture-handler internally.
Could someone provide guidance on how to blend custom gestures with those of the carousel?
